# Display alert on button submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have built a very basic application system. I have made one page where I can see all the applications in a table via MySQL query. I have also made so I can click a button to either approve or deny the application. Dependning on which button I press, the row with that specific user will be moved do the approved or denied table in the database. But, I want to display an alert when pressing the different buttons at the same time they send the row id to the PHP code.

Here is my code for the application table site: (register.php)

```
 <?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ansokningar";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    
?>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th> ID </th>
          <th> Förnamn </th>
          <th>Efternamn </th>
          <th>Mejladress</th>
          <th>Ålder</th>
          <th>Ansökt som</th>
          <th>Läs Ansökning</th>
          <th>Godkänn</th>
          <th>Neka</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)        
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
           ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php  echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row['fornamn']; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row['efternamn']; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row['mejladress']; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row['alder']; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row['intresseradavyrket']; ?></td>
        
            
     
        <td>
            <form action="register.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" id="deleteid" name="delete" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
             <center> <button id="delete" type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></center>
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
        } 
    }
    else {
      
      echo $ingaansokning;
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

And here is my PHP code for moving the row: (neka.php)

```
<?PHP require '../db/dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "
    
    INSERT INTO nekade SELECT * FROM ansokningar WHERE  id='$id';
    DELETE FROM ansokningar WHERE id='$id';
    "; 
     $query_run = $link->multi_query($query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['success'] = '';
        header('Location: ../../register.php');
        exit();
```

How do I send the row ID from the first page to the second and display one alert when it's done?
I have tried this on the first page (register.php) but it doesn't work:

```
<script>

    $(function(){
      $('#delete').click(function() {

        var id = <?php echo $row['id']; ?>;

       
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'includes/ansokningar/neka.php',
          data:{id: id},
          success: function(data){

            Swal.fire(
                             'Grattis!',
                             'Din ansökan är nu skickad!',
                             'success'
                            )   

            }

          


        })
      })
    });
```

(Without the ajax stuff it works to move the user to the other table)
Thanks!

Comment: you can't use php on here: `var id = <?php echo $row['id']; ?>;`  because php is processed when you open the page. you have to take the id with javascript

Comment: try something like `var id = $(this).parents('form').find('input').val()` or  `$(this).parents('tr').find('td:first').text()` that's two place that you put the `$row['id']`. also avoid using values in the id attribute that aren't unique.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up and using `data-vars` so you can put the needed variable data on the button that is clicked itself. Then you simply get it as `$(this).data('rowid')`.